# Is there a way to share mutable state amongst enum variants?

Tags: enums, rust, mutable

I'm currently using enums in my Rust code and I implemented the Display trait for them. However, whenever I call to_string() on this enum, I want the fmt function in the Display trait to access some shared string that can be seen by all enum variants. Once I have that string, I will write it to a file. Currently I am just opening a file and writing to it for every to_string call instead. Here is what I have:

```
use std::fmt;
use std::fs;

pub enum Ast {
    A,
    B,
    C,
}

impl fmt::Display for Ast {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Ast::A => {
                foo();
                write!(f, " ... ")
            }
            Ast::B => {
                foo();
                write!(f, "...")
            }
            Ast::C => {
                foo();
                write!(f, "...")
            }
        }
    }
}

fn foo() {
    let data: String = String::from("This is data");
    fs::write("src/file.txt", data).expect("Could not open file");
}
```

Instead I would like to declare a String variable at the top of the file that foo would be able to access and mutate. Is there any way to do this? Thank you

Comment: Writing to a file in a `Display` impl seems very wrong. It will be unexpected to anyone using your code and likely to cause problems. It probably indicates that you are approaching something from the wrong angle, or trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: It is not possible to mutate state inside a `&self` receiver, you best bet might be a static variable that uses some sync strategy.

Comment: @Caio: It is possible, actually, using Cells. It's also unexpected, so warrants a very good reason.